# std::bind null function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef int(*SumFptr)(int,int);

int main()
{

    SumFptr ptr = nullptr;
    std::function<int(int)> func = std::bind(ptr, std::placeholders::_1, 42);
    std::cout << (func ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is true.

My expectation was false, like `std::function{nullptr}`. Is it a bug or correct behaviour and where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

How is the `std::function` supposed to know that the object it was constructed with contains a null pointer?

As far as it's concerned it has a callable object, it can't know that it is a callable object containing a null pointer (which would crash if called).

When you construct `std::function{nullptr}` it knows it doesn't have a callable object, and behaves exactly as if you'd called the default constructor.  `std::function{ anything_else }` causes it to store `anything_else` and unless it is a null pointer (not an object that wraps a null pointer!) will consider itself to have a target object.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool

> `std::function::operator bool`
>   Return value: `true` if `*this` stores a callable function target, `false` otherwise.

Put another way, your program is almost exactly equivalent to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using SumFPtr = int(*)(int,int);

struct BoundFunction {    
    SumFptr fptr;
    int y;

    int operator()(int x) const { return fptr(x, y); }
};

BoundFunction bind(SumFPtr fptr, int y)
{
    return BoundFunction{fptr, y};
}

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> func = bind(nullptr, 42);
    std::cout << (func ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
}
```

Now it should be obvious that of course it prints `"true"`, because the `std::function` contains a callable object.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it easy to check arguments for bind? Like:
bind(func, ...) { if (!func) save_nullptr_callable() }

Comment: It would be theoretically possible, but `std::function` would have to know how to check for that. Do you see anything like that specified in the standard? Why should `bind` be a special case, when the same wouldn't work for my `BoundFunction` or for a lambda that captures a null function pointer?

Comment: Also, you could have some `func` that is a valid callable object but `!func` is true, so you'd need to be more careful to correctly identify a null pointer.